# Serial.WriteLine("My message!"); Appending?

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to send a message from a C# application to my arduino on the serial port.

However it hangs on the WriteLine. It never ends and when I read whats been stored in my buffer on the arduino it's like ive been sending it over and over 100 times.

Code on c# app

```
public void testSend()
    {
        if (mySerialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            //setup
            //mySerialPort.Open();
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            try 
            {
                mySerialPort.WriteLine("Sent from my c# app!");
            }
            catch(TimeoutException)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Timeout while sending data");
            }

            //mySerialPort.Close();
        }
        else 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Port already open!"); 
        }

    }
```

Code on arduino(for reference and clearance )

```
    void setup()
    {
        //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
        Serial.begin(9600);
        while (!Serial)
        {
            ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
        }
    }
    char* buf = malloc(1024);

    int ReciveData()
    {

        if (Serial.available())
        {
            // read the incoming bytes:
            String temp = Serial.readString();
            if (temp.length() > 0)
            {
                temp.toCharArray(buf, temp.length() + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    void loop()
    {
        Serial.print("Sent from arduino!");
        Serial.println(buf);
        delay(1000);
        ReciveData();
    } 
}
```

This is how it looks. Here is 4 messages, every send start with "Sent from arduino!". when i read it. You can see on line 1 and 2 everything is good but when I start the c# application and it goes Hawaii

```
Sent from arduino!Sent from serial terminal!
Sent from arduino!Sent from serial terminal!
Sent from arduino!Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!

Sent from arduino!Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
Sent from my c# app!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why. But when i tried to add \0 at end of the string it worked.

```
        try 
        {
            mySerialPort.WriteLine("Sent from my c# app! \0");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In c \0 is the string terminator character. Without it the read won't know the characher array has ended.

Comment: I know that but this is c#. I thought the c# function would send anyway.

Comment: C# doesn't contain the premise of a string terminator, some work in a different way in that their objects also contain length information, so a terminating character is not needed, and imho is just confusing. Therefore of the unmanaged code your speaking to needs a binary null character added to the transmission then it needs to be added explicitly.

Comment: Sorry for the typos above, apparently you can't edit a comment.  I meant STRINGS (in #) work in a different way, and that IF the unmanaged code...

Answer (score 0):

The `mySerialPort.WriteLine` method would send the string you specified + the `mySerialPort.NewLine` value, which in your case is the default value - `System.Environment.NewLine` (which is  `"\r\n"`).

Before the usage of `WriteLine` (and also `ReadLine`) - specify the protocol EOL character, in your case:

```
mySerialPort.NewLine = "\0"
```

And there will be no need to add manually the EOL character on each writing (and to miss the purpose of `WriteLine` over just `Write`)